# Generating FeatureLayer From FeatureCollection With ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Can you please take a look at [**This Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/0su725rz/) and let me if this is doable to create a `FeatureLayer` from `featureCollection` without using `URL`

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
   var schoolData = {"schools":[
    { "latitude":49.2752, "longitude":-123.0719, "name":"King George" },
    { "latitude":49.2627, "longitude":-123.1636, "name":"Britannia" },
    { "latitude":49.2253, "longitude":-123.0442, "name":"Killarney" }
]};

var featureCollection = {
          "layerDefinition": null,
          "featureSet": {
            "features": [],
            "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint"
          }
        };
        featureCollection.layerDefinition = {
          "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
          "objectIdField": "ObjectID",
          "drawingInfo": {
            "renderer": {
              "type": "simple",
              "symbol": {
                "type": "esriPMS",
                "width": 15,
                "height": 15
              }
            }
          },
          "fields": [{
            "name": "ObjectID",
            "alias": "ObjectID",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeOID"
          }, {
            "name": "latitude",
            "alias": "Description",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeGeometry"
          }, {
            "name": "longitude",
            "alias": "Title",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeGeometry"
          },{
            "name": "name",
            "alias": "Description",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeString"
          }]
        };

var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection, { id: 'schoolsLayer'  });

 map.addLayers(featureLayer);

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your code working.  check your JS http://jsonlint.com/  the commented projection info caused a problem.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">  
    <title>FeatureLayer</title>  

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.15/esri/css/esri.css">  
    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.15/"></script>  
    <!--<script src="travel6.json" type="text/javascript"></script>  -->  
    <style>  
        html, body, #map {  
            padding: 0;  
            margin: 0;  
            height: 100%;  
            width: 100%;  
        }  
    </style>  

    <script>  
        require([  
            "esri/map", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", "esri/Color", "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",  
            "esri/tasks/FeatureSet", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",  
            "dojo/domReady!"  
        ], function(  
            Map, SimpleMarkerSymbol, Color, SimpleRenderer,  
            FeatureSet, FeatureLayer  
        ) {  

  //My example was from https://geonet.esri.com/thread/171775


            var map = new Map("map", {  
  basemap: "gray",
  center: [-123.141608, 49.245291],
  zoom: 1 
            });  

                     map.on('load', function() {  
                    var jsonFS = {
  "displayFieldName": "Name",
  "fieldAliases": {
    "Name": "Name"
  },
  "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
  "spatialReference": {
    "wkid": 102100 
  },
  "fields": [{
    "name": "Name",
    "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
    "alias": "Name"
  }],
  "features": [{
    "attributes": {
      "Name": "1"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "x": -8919439.31450887,
      "y": 4928270.761925456
    }
  }, {
    "attributes": {
      "Name": "2"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "x": -8155495.379532158,
      "y": 5075380.311392084
    }
  }]
};

                var fs = new FeatureSet(jsonFS); 


    var layerDefinition = {
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
    "drawingInfo": {
      "renderer": {
        "type": "simple",
        "symbol": {
          "type": "esriPMS",
          "style": "esriSMSSquare",
          "color": [76, 115, 0, 255],
          "width": 50,
          "height": 50
        }
      }
    },
    "fields": [{
      "name": "Name",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
      "alias": "Name"
    }]
  };

                var featureCollection = {  
                    layerDefinition : layerDefinition,  
                    featureSet : fs  
                };  

                featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection);  
                var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol().setColor(new esri.Color([255,0,0,0.5]));  
                var renderer = new SimpleRenderer(symbol);  
                featureLayer.setRenderer(renderer);  

                map.addLayer(featureLayer);  
            });  

        });  
        </script>  
    </head>  

    <body class='claro'>  
        <div id="map" style="width:900px; height:600px;" ></div>  
    </body>  

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [enter link description here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8896/feature-layer-with-ondemand-mode/8912#8912) It's not in AMD style but the answer should help. Look for ArcGIS and JSON, it should help, worse case look at Leafelt JS, it's simple there.

Comment: Thanks for reply Bill, I updated the code based on what you said but still not getting any symbol on map. Here is the demo https://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/x8h62b26/1/